# JPA Criteria on PostgreSQL boolean type creates invalid query

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I have a regular JPA Entity which has a boolean field:

```java
@Entity("UserAccount")
public class UserAccount {

   ...

   @Column(name = "isActive")
   private boolean isActive = false;

   ...
  
}
```

This is backed by a table in PostgreSQL 15. In the table definition, the field is of type `BOOLEAN` (**not** integer!):

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserAccount(
   ...
   isActive BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   ...
)
```

When I attempt to use the JPA Criteria API with it:

```
criteriaBuilder.isTrue(root.get("isActive"))
```

... then it will be rendered as  `= 1` in the SQL query which is sent to PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM UserAccount
WHERE isActive = 1
```

PostgreSQL rejects this query with the following error (which is pretty clear):

```
PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**My question is:** how can I tell Hibernate that I'm using an actual PostgreSQL-native `BOOLEAN` type in my table instead of encoding the boolean as a number?

Comment: How did you tell hibernate you are using a Postgres database? Did you maybe set a hibernate.dialect property somewhere for a different DB type?

Comment: @Chris your comment was spot-on, thank you very much! Somewhere deep down in our persistence config, the dialect of our previous DBMS was hardcoded and we're migrating to postgres now. I'm using PostGreSQL10Dialect now and it's working nicely. Thanks!